# In a React application, how to render a component once by passing it two arrays at the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a component only once by passing it two arrays and I want it to take the first element of the first array and the first element of the second array and render once and so on. i am trying to use the map() method since they are arrays heres what i have tried:-

1. combine them in a new array but it didn't work well
2. comnine them in a new object and i could not find an equivalent for the map() method

```
function AddNotes() {
  const [noteDraft, setNoteDraft] = useState('');
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [titleDraft, setTitleDraft] = useState('');
  const [titles, setTitles] = useState([]);

  const wholeNote = [notes, titles];

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!noteDraft && !titleDraft) return;
    onAddItems(noteDraft, titleDraft);
    setNoteDraft('');
    setTitleDraft('');
  }

  function onAddItems(note, title) {
    setNotes(notes => [...notes, note]);
    setTitles(titles => [...titles, title]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="enter your title..."
          value={titleDraft}
          onChange={e => setTitleDraft(e.target.value)}
        />
        <>
          <textarea
            type="text"
            placeholder="type your note..."
            rows="7"
            cols="60"
            wrap="hard"
            value={noteDraft}
            onChange={e => setNoteDraft(e.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
          <button>Add note</button>
        </>
      </form>
      <div>
        {wholeNote.map(note => (
          <SingleNote note={[...note[0]]} title={[...note[1]]} key={notes} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the two arrays are supposed to show the title of a note and its body (description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your map method you should use an array of objects, like this:

```
let noteList = [Object1, Object2, ...]
```

Each Object will be like this:

```
noteOne = {title: "abc", desc: "xyz", ...}
```

If you want access to title's property, then use: noteOne.title. The same for description.
If you want access to title of noteOne from noteList, then use: noteList[0].title

Comment: thank you so much for your help, this is exactly the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an `Object` to render with `map()` as an `Array`, we have some solution as:

1. `Object.values(yourObject)` -> this will return an array of values of your object
2. `Object.entries(yourObject)`-> this will return an array of keys, values of your object

then you can use `map()`

You can refer this, hope it match your problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pmo76x?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: thank you so much for your help and your effort, man. wish you the best

Answer (score 1):

You are maintaining two separate collections for storing the title and the description. But during rendering you are putting together both the arrays into another array and then mapping over the resultant array. As this resultant array will always contain 2 sub-arrays, mapping over this will run the `.map` callback twice, thereby rendering the callback's component twice.

As a good practice, it is always suggested to store related data together, i.e., the title and the description in this case. You can have a collection of objects with each object having the properties `title` and `description`.
Then, you can map over this array containing note objects.

After the changes, your code would look something like this:

```
function AddNotes() {
  const [noteDraft, setNoteDraft] = useState('');
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [titleDraft, setTitleDraft] = useState('');
  const [titles, setTitles] = useState([]);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!noteDraft && !titleDraft) return;
    onAddItems(noteDraft, titleDraft);
    setNoteDraft('');
    setTitleDraft('');
  }

  function onAddItems(note, title) {
    setNotes(notes => [...notes, {note, title}]); //Use notes as a single state to maintain the collection of both title and description
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="enter your title..."
          value={titleDraft}
          onChange={e => setTitleDraft(e.target.value)}
        />
        <>
          <textarea
            type="text"
            placeholder="type your note..."
            rows="7"
            cols="60"
            wrap="hard"
            value={noteDraft}
            onChange={e => setNoteDraft(e.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
          <button>Add note</button>
        </>
      </form>
      <div>
        {notes.map(note => (
          <SingleNote note={note.note} title={note.title} key={note.note+note.title} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help and your effort, man. your way of explanation was really clear and straightforward, thanks for your effort again.